# How to find each equation for a set of five equidistant points around a unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

Given a unit circle I want to make five points around it that are the same distance from each other. I know that in order to make four I can do $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)$.

But how can I do this on a five point algorithm?

Comment: You want them $72^{\circ}$ apart. Do you know how to rotate a point around origin by an angle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $n$th roots of unity are $n$ equidistant points on the unit circle. The $k$th such point for $0\le k<n$ is given by
$$e^{2\pi ik/n}=\cos\frac{2\pi k}n+i\sin\frac{2\pi k}n\implies\left(\cos\frac{2\pi k}n,\sin\frac{2\pi k}n\right)$$
For $n=4$ this reduces to the coordinates you gave.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Would you mind giving this equation in degrees?

Comment: $$360^\circ/n$$.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel -- I just deleted my comment. I used the equation you gave and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MarcPerry Now, accept my answer by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: Sorry. I just deleted that before you answered. My real question was what if the starting point was offset 10 degrees in radians?

Comment: @MarcPerry Then just replace $2\pi k/n$ by $2\pi k/n+10^\circ$. 72° becomes 82°, etc.